# Convert a quaternion from NED right handed to ENU left handed

Tags: quaternion

My drone's camera rotation is calculated using NED Right handed quaternion and I want to convert it to ENU left-handed.

Comment: X: East, Y: North, Z: Up is a right-handed coordinate system. You can't do that with your left hand with your thumb as X, index finger as Y, and middle finger as Z.

Comment: Have you reviewed previous Q&A about [how to convert a quaternion between coordinate systems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/140487/39518)? (more [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/157954/39518) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/141249/39518)) Show us what you've tried based on your research thus far, and how the output differs from what you expect.